# passing String to loadUrl not working

Tags: android, android-studio

For following code :

```
public void onbuttonclick(){
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    w1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    b1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                String url = e1.getText().toString();

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    w1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                    w1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    w1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                    w1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    w1.loadUrl(url);
                }
            }
    );
```

}

When I type "https://www.google.com" in text box and click button nothing happens but if I replace url with "https://www.google.com" in loadUrl() method it works fine.

I am new to android and java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you are getting the url from text box when you register the event. At that point the text box is empty.

You have to read the url when you actually click the button.
That being said, move the `String url = e1.getText().toString();` line inside the onClick method.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch url in `onClick` method :

```
b1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
 String url = e1.getText().toString();
                    w1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                    w1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    w1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                    w1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    w1.loadUrl(url);
                }
            }
    );
```